# Find the effective date of the latest order against an account

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I am looking for a query which will help me to find the Account_no, latest order and the effective date of the latest order on that account for all the accounts in the table. Sample table as below.

| Account_no | order_id | effective_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | ord1 | 01012023 |
| 100 | ord2 | 03042023 |
| 101 | ord1 | 01012023 |

Query result:

| Account_no | order_id | effective_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | ord2 | 03042023 |
| 101 | ord1 | 01012023 |

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_NO,TOP1 ORDID FROM ORDER.
```

Comment: Have you researched this problem yet?  There are many answers on this site which explain how to do this.